# Convex Sets and Linear Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Consider the set $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R_+ \times   \Bbb R \text{ s.t. } y\leq \ln x - e^x\}$. This set is:

A) A linear subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

B) Convex

C) Convex & a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

D) neither convex nor linear subspace of $\mathbb R^2$

I got the part that the set should be convex. I drew a rough graph of the set and it can be viewed as the negative of the distance between the graphs of $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$. So $y$ being negative, first increases at a decreasing rate, reaches a max(still negative) and then decreases at an increasing rate, giving us a concave shaped graph in the fourth quadrant. The entire space below this graph and the graph itself is what the set mentioned in the above question is. What I don't understand although, is if this is a linear subspace. how to find that out?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.  It seems like you wanted to write
$$
\{(x,y) \in [\Bbb R + x \Bbb R] \text{s.t. } y\dots?\}
$$
What does $[\Bbb R + x \Bbb R] $ mean?  What is the rest of the definition of the set?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't format the question properly. It means the set is a cartesian product of set of non negative real numbers and set of all real numbers. in the ordered pair (x,y), x can only take non negative real values and y can take any real value. The first and fourth quadrants basically. And y is less than or equal to lnx - e^x

Comment: @divyagarg What have you tried ?

Comment: @Leth I got the part that the set should be convex. I drew a rough graph of the set and it can be viewed as the negative of the distance between the graphs of e^x and ln(x). So y being negative, first increases at a decreasing rate, reaches a max(still negative) and then decreases at an increasing rate, giving us a concave shaped graph in the fourth quadrant. The entire space below this graph and the graph itself is what the set mentioned in the above question is. What I don't understand although, is if this is a linear subspace. how to find that out?

Comment: @divyagarg I suggests you to add this last comment of your to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What's the relationship between convex functions and convex sets?

In $\Bbb R^2$, the only linear subspaces are all of $\Bbb R^2$, lines through the origin, and the set $\{(0,0)\}$.  It should be clear that this set is none of these things.